# What is meaning of 'following a heated news conference'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

Can you paraphrase and explain meaning for 'following a heated news conference'. It sounds complicated for me not native speaker. 'Following' and 'heated' particulary.

> The administration removed Acosta’s press pass **following a heated** news
>   conference last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **following** just means "after." So the White House revoked Acosta's press pass after the news conference. **Heated** is an adjective modifying "news conference," and it means "tense" or "emotional," usually in that the participants were angry. "Heated" is often used to modify the word "argument" when people are shouting at one another.